# What content type should i use with .cfa sound file to play with j2me?

Tags: audio, java-me, audioformat

I m using the following code for play a sound file in j2me

```
           try
            {
        String ctype_1 = "audio/x-wav";// #LINE 1
        temp = Manager.createPlayer(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(audioFileString),ctype_1 );
        if(temp != null){
            temp.setLoopCount(1);
            temp.realize();
            temp.prefetch() ;
            return temp;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("MediaException in my sound ==>"+ex);
    }
```

at comment // #LINE 1  we have to give the content type (in this the type is for .wav file)

My question is that what content type i should give for the sound file .caf extension.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK .cfa file isn't supported by Java ME. Go through these articles,

[MMAPI for Java ME](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=375708)

[Finding audio format in Java ME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/CS001260_-_Finding_audio_and_video_formats_supported_by_the_phone_in_Java_ME)